# Is it safe to extend a NSManagedObject entity object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am in the process of making an application for the iPhone. I am using core data to store a lot of information but have come across a slight stumbling block.

As a very simplistic example I have an entity that has a password attribute. This attribute is optional.

I have automatically generated a NSManagedObject subclass.

What I would like to do is extend this subclass for the following reason. The password is optional. If the user decides that the app should not remember the password then I would like a custome getter and setter for this attribute.

The setter would check if the password should be stored. If it should then it passes it to the  entity subclass. If not my own subclass stores the information.

The getter would check where the password resides and return this.

The advantage would be the class would behave the same regardless of whether the password is stored in the core data model or not.

I have tried to do some searching to see if this will cause any problems but not really coming across much at present.

Comment: Are you saying that the password will be stored one way or another? Either in Core Data or in your own storage?

Comment: Hi. No slight misunderstanding. If the user elects for the app to remember the password it would be stored in the core data. If they choose for the app not to remember the password the user would be requested the first time it is needed and it would be stored in my own subclass for the lifetime of the apps instance.

Comment: Oh alright. When you said it would be stored in an instance, I was not sure whether or not it was being stored or not. I found it odd that it would get stored no matter what the user chooses, but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to do this. You can do this via either a `category` or custom `setters` and `getters` on your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

However, ***be careful with your custom `setters` and `getters`.***

You will need to use `NSManagedObject`'s instance methods for getting and setting primitive values (managed by the data model).

For getting primitives, use `primitiveValueForKey:`. For setting, use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`.

In this situation, I'd create a custom setter for the `password` attribute on your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Something like this

```
- (void)setPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    BOOL shouldSetPassword = ... // your custom logic here to determine if the password should be set or not

    if (!shouldSetPassword)
        return;

    NSString *key = @"password";
    NSString *value = [self primitiveValueForKey:key];

    if (value == password)
        return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:password forKey:key];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Hey this looks to address exactly what I meant. Cheers